# Write a function to filter multiple excel files in the directory and rbind the results

Tags: r, excel, function, dataframe

I have multiple excel files in my directory of the same format. I want to write a function that reads through these files and filters them as shown, then rbinds all of the rows to one final dataframe.
It would be nice to have an id column to identify which file these rows are coming from.

```
library(readxl)

apply_fun <- function(filename) {
data <- readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = "Section Cut Forces - Design", 
                           skip = 1, col_names = TRUE) ; data <- data[-1,] ;

data <- subset(data, "StepTye" == "Max")                                  
Moment <- data[,c(1,2,6,10)]

Moment
}

filenames <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)
out <- data.frame(t(sapply(filenames, apply_fun)))
```

Here are two of the excel files as

[84-9-S00.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Lhf79tRmcZRXkj0vFe5Ukr9dYDQbUq3E/view?usp=sharing)

[84-9-S07.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dzo37vMFga0v9YekzUFTReT5VfHTN0WE/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Use `do.call()` to `rbind` all files that will be stored in a list `L`. Here the code:

```
library(readxl)
#Function
apply_fun <- function(filename) {
  data <- readxl::read_excel(filename, sheet = "Section Cut Forces - Design", 
                             skip = 1, col_names = TRUE)
  data <- data[-1,]
  data <- subset(data, StepType == "Max")
  Moment <- data[,c(1,2,6,10)]
  Moment$id <- filename
  return(Moment)
}
#Code
filenames <- list.files(pattern = "\\.xlsx", full.names = TRUE)
L <- lapply(filenames,apply_fun)
#Bind
Out <- do.call(rbind,L)
```

Output with test file (Some rows):

```
head(Out)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  SectionCut OutputCase V2                 M3                 id             
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>              <chr>              <chr>          
1 1          LL-3       35.317999999999998 51208.425000000003 ./84-9-S00.xlsx
2 1          LL-2       35.917999999999999 48494.190999999999 ./84-9-S00.xlsx
3 1          LL-1       26.937999999999999 33676.78           ./84-9-S00.xlsx
4 2          LL-3       37.884999999999998 14.86              ./84-9-S00.xlsx
5 2          LL-2       32.731999999999999 14.372999999999999 ./84-9-S00.xlsx
6 2          LL-1       23.114999999999998 10.484             ./84-9-S00.xlsx
```

Output 2:

```
# A tibble: 35 x 5
   SectionCut OutputCase V2                 M3                 id             
   <chr>      <chr>      <chr>              <chr>              <chr>          
 1 1          LL-3       35.317999999999998 51208.425000000003 ./84-9-S00.xlsx
 2 1          LL-2       35.917999999999999 48494.190999999999 ./84-9-S00.xlsx
 3 1          LL-1       26.937999999999999 33676.78           ./84-9-S00.xlsx
 4 2          LL-3       37.884999999999998 14.86              ./84-9-S00.xlsx
 5 2          LL-2       32.731999999999999 14.372999999999999 ./84-9-S00.xlsx
 6 2          LL-1       23.114999999999998 10.484             ./84-9-S00.xlsx
 7 3          LL-3       38.220999999999997 57100.021000000001 ./84-9-S00.xlsx
 8 3          LL-2       37.587000000000003 53050.275999999998 ./84-9-S00.xlsx
 9 3          LL-1       24.864999999999998 36847.82           ./84-9-S00.xlsx
10 Left       LL-3       31.035             49882.42           ./84-9-S00.xlsx
# ... with 25 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i can see what you are doing but I am getting an error when i try to apply. the error is "Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, id, value = "./84-12-S00.xlsx") : replacement has 1 row, data has 0" `"./84-12-S00.xlsx"` is a sample excel file

Comment: @MaralDorri Maybe could you share the excel file in a downloadable link to test the function again? The dput will not work as the excel file needs to be checked.

Comment: I just updated the original post with a google drive link

Comment: @MaralDorri I added an update and tested with the file provided. Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: I just checked the update, when i remove the " from `StepType` then i get the error "Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : object 'StepTye' not found" I am not sure how it ran for you though...

Comment: I just added a second excel file as an example

Comment: @MaralDorri I have run with the new file and works (added global output).

Comment: @MaralDorri The issue looks like you must set `StepType` instead of `StepTye` as the last one does not exist. Let me know how that goes!